# Can one disable the sbt 1.x server?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

Some of my builds and plugins make use of private deployment credentials (sometimes read from the file system, sometimes entered and retained in memory via the `InteractionService`).

Though perhaps it is overparanoid, I try to be careful to minimize the attack surface of software that uses private information, and it feels like bad hygiene to run a server, even on localhost or a UNIX socket, unnecessarily in these builds.

I've looked for a setting I could set in a plugin that would disable server startup unless overridden by the build. So far have not found anything like this. Is there such a setting?

Many thanks!

---

**Update:** With the help of Eugene Yokota, as of sbt 1.1.1 there is now a boolean `autoStartServer` setting. Builds and plugins can prevent the server from starting up automatically by setting `autoStartServer := false`. (Users can still manually start-up the server by running `startServer` if they wish.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of sbt 1.1.0 at least, the server won't start unless you start the sbt shell, which means that if you're running sbt in batch mode (for example `sbt test`) in CI environment, it won't have server.

To stop server even in the shell automatically, I've added a JVM flag `sbt.server.autostart`. So running sbt as `sbt -Dsbt.server.autostart=false` would do it. You can globally set that by putting that into your `SBT_OPTS`.

To manually opt-in for server, you can then run:

```
> startServer
```

**Update**: Now that `autoStartServer` is a setting, you can write the following in `~/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt`:

```scala
// This is so it works on sbt 1.x prior to 1.1.1
SettingKey[Boolean]("autoStartServer", "") := false
```

Comment: Thanks! I can do that for now. But I'm working on a security sensitive plugin, intended for interactive use, that I mean to distribute. It'd really be helpful if there were a setting by which plugin could prevent autostart of the server (overridable of course by the ultimate build). Those in the know can use the system property, I can document and recommend it, but most users will likely never bother. I'd really like to be as secure as possible by default. Of course, rather than bug you, I could look into trying to contribute such a thing. Thank you for all your work!

Comment: For what it's worth, I've offered a pull request to perhaps implement this feature for sbt-1.1.1.